# Indefinite article "une"

Tags: articles

I'm reading *Easy French Step-by-Step*

[image]

IMHO, *une* is an indefinite article in French, so its correspondence in English is *a/an*. Could you please elaborate on how the sentence *Il y a une touriste devant le musée* is translated as *There’s a tourist in front of the museum*, but not *There’s a tourist in front of a museum*?

Comment: *Un/une* are the indefinte articles, *le/la/les* are the definite articles. *Une touriste* → *a tourist*; *le musée* → *the museum*. In this sentence, the English indefinite and definite articles correspond exactly with the French ones. Could you explain why you are confused?

Comment: Oh my bad @PeterShor. Please post your comment as answer to remove this question from the answered list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Un/une* are the indefinte articles, *le/la/les* are the definite articles.

*Une touriste* → *a tourist*; *le musée* → *the museum*.

In this sentence, the English indefinite and definite articles correspond exactly with the French ones (which is often not the case). Could you explain why you are confused?